# Determine the area of convergence and the sum-function for the power series $\sum_{n \geq 0} n(z-2)^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, solution-verification

I would like to verify that my proof of the following exercise is correct:

Determine the area of convergence and the sum-function for the power series 
$$
\sum_{n \geq 0} n(z-2)^n. 
$$
**Proof:** 
Firstly, we notice that this is a power series with coefficient $c_n = n$. Hence, we compute the radius of convergence as 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}} \right| = \frac{n}{n+1} = 1. 
$$
So this series converges for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z-2| < 1$, in other words, in the open ball $B(2,1)$.

Now we compute the sum function. Firstly, notice that the Cauchy-product of the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z-2)^n$ with itself is given by 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n (z-2)^k (z-2)^{n-k} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)(z-2)^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n(z-2)^n + \sum_{n=0}^\infty (z-2)^n. 
$$
Now by the geometric series we have in the area of convergence $|z-2| < 1$, 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z-2)^n = \frac{1}{1-(z-2)} = \frac{1}{3-z}. 
$$
Moreover, we know that the cauchyproduct of two series converges to the product of the limit of both series. So from this we know that 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(z-2)^n + \sum_{n=0}^\infty (z-2)^n = \frac{1}{(3-z)^2}
$$
Hence we compute 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(z-2)^n = \frac{1}{(3-z)^2} - \sum_{n=0}^\infty (z-2)^n = \frac{1}{(3-z)^2} - \frac{1}{3-z} = \frac{z-3}{(3-z)^2}. 
$$

Comment: Small mistake in the very last equality sign: $$\frac{1}{(3-z)^2}-\frac{1}{3-z} = \frac{z-2}{(3-z)^2} \neq \frac{z-3}{(3-z)^2}.$$

Comment: You're right, thanks!